# Why is my nested array of Structs overwriting previously stored values?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So basically here I am just seeing whether my previously stored input, that is **`temp->voterDetails[0].name`**, has its value restored after another input.
Unfortunately it does not seem to store its value. Could you help me understanding why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Voter {
    char *name;
};

struct Block{
    // Creating a block containing 5 voter details
    struct Voter voterDetails[5];
};

int main() {
    int choice;
    struct Block *Genesis = (struct Block *)malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
    struct Block *temp = Genesis;
    struct Block *newnode = (struct Block *)malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
    char *nm;
    int voteNum = 0;
    int blockNumber = 1;
    do{
        printf("What do you want to do\n1. Cast a vote\n2. Check your vote\n3. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter name");
                fgets(nm, 30, stdin);
                fgets(nm, 30, stdin);
                voteNum += 1;
                temp->voterDetails[voteNum-1].name = nm;
                puts(Genesis->voterDetails[0].name);

                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you keep assigning the same variable `nm` to the stored values.  You must make a copy of the string (and release it when you are done with it).

Comment: sorry to bother but how would I release it. I have used strcpy to copy the string. What next?

Comment: Furthermore apparently no allocation is done for the `nm` temporary char pointer.

Comment: Use `strdup(nm)` to make a copy of the string. When you're done with them, do `free(Genesis->voterDetails[i].name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allocating any space for your pointers.  This doesn't happen "automatically" in C, you have to manually do it.  From your `fgets` argument of `30`, it seems you want to accept names with a max of 30 chars.  If that's the case, then the easiest thing to do is simply use `char` arrays instead of pointers:

```c
struct Voter {
    char name[30]; // note because of the required NUL terminator, this
                   // will only fit 29 printable characters
};
```

and the same for `nm`

```c
char nm[30] = { 0 };  // initializes the array to 0s, altho fgets
                      // will always add a NUL terminator
```

But even with those fixes, you still need to *copy* the string data entered in `nm` to your `name`s:

```c
#include <string.h>
...
strcpy(temp->voterDetails[voteNum-1].name, nm);
```

Or IMHO, there's no point in using the temp `nm` anyway, just plug `temp->voterDetails[voteNum].name` directly into `fgets`.  Also note that `fgets` will add a newline to the array if you don't max out the buffer size.  You can search for ways to remove that if you don't want it.

If you want to use pointers instead of arrays, you must `malloc` space for `name` and `nm` as you have for your `struct Block` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a lot of issues:

1. `nm` temporary pointer (that in your snippet isn't even necessary, but I assume it can be useful in the whole program) is not initialized. It should be allocated, instead
2. Each element of the array `temp->voterDetails[voteNum].name` has to be allocated as well
3. Strings cannot be assigned like variables belonging to base types such as integers (`str1 = str2;` make those strings actually point to the same data). They can be copied using `strcpy` function
4. Whenever you perform a `choice` the newline remains in the input buffer, making the first `fgets` return immediately with no data. That's what you "solved" calling `fgets` twice, but it's not a real solution
5. Data read with `fgets` will have trailing newline, that will have to be removed from the `name` buffer

Here it is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_VOTERS 5

struct Voter {
    char *name;
};

struct Block{
    // Creating a block containing 5 voter details
    struct Voter voterDetails[MAX_VOTERS];
};

void flushInput(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    struct Block *Genesis = (struct Block *)malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
    struct Block *temp = Genesis;
    struct Block *newnode = (struct Block *)malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
    char *nm = malloc(30 * sizeof(char)); // nm temporary pointer allocation
    int voteNum = 0;
    int blockNumber = 1;
    do{
        printf("What do you want to do\n1. Cast a vote\n2. Check your vote\n3. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        flushInput();
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter name\n"); // Better with a newline
                fgets(nm, 30, stdin);   // Useless extra fgets removed
                nm[strcspn(nm, "\n")] = 0;
                temp->voterDetails[voteNum].name = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(temp->voterDetails[voteNum].name, nm);   // Strings cannot be assigned, but are copied with strcpy
                                                                // voteNum incremented later, so '-1' can be avoided. Isn't it more readable?
                printf("Name: %s..\n", Genesis->voterDetails[voteNum].name); // printf used instead of puts, in order to append a newline
                voteNum += 1;
                
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3 && voteNum < MAX_VOTERS); // The program is safer if you check that votes don't exceed the number of location in your array

    free(nm);
    /* ... remember to free all the remaining pointers as soon as you don't need them anymore */
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
What do you want to do
1. Cast a vote
2. Check your vote
3. Exit
1
Enter name
Roberto
Name: Roberto
What do you want to do
1. Cast a vote
2. Check your vote
3. Exit
...
```

Some extra comments:

1. Pending data in `stdin` is flushed using the custom function `flushInput()` (consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/11336762) for more details)
2. After flushing correctly the input buffer, the extra `fgets` can be removed
3. It's always better to make sure that the user doesn't insert data we don't have room for. In this case, since the `voterDetails` array has 5 elements, we make sure to exit the loop as soon as the fifth name has been inserted
4. Since the constant '5' is now used several times, it is better to avoid using "magic numbers" in the code. Just define a precompiler constant, instead (`MAX_VOTERS`)

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Uninitialized/assign value**

Calling `fgets(nm, 30, stdin);` yet `nm` is not yet assigned.  UB